# Subspaces for the set of polynomials with the property $p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials. Let $A \subset P$ such that for every polynomial the following holds $p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=0$. Give an example of a subspace $V \subset A$ and $A \subset W$ such that $\{0\} \ne V \ne A$ and $A \ne W \ne P$.

The last conditions seem very confusing to me. What's with all the, not equal restrictions?

For the first part I would need to find a subset $V$ of $A$ for which the following properties hold.

1. $0 \in V$
2. If $u,v \in V$ then $u+v \in V$
3. If $u \in V$ then $cu\in V$, when $c\in \mathbb{R}$

If $P$ is the set of all polynomials and $A$ is a subset of $P$ could I take $V$ to be for example the set of polynomials of let's say degree $3$ for which the condition holds? Any hints on this would be appreciated...

Comment: Considering the last conditions: I agree they look somewhat confusing. What they are saying is that you're not allowed to present the trivial solutions, where you just take $V$ to be the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ (i.e. the zero polynomial), or the other trivial solution where you $W$ to be the whole space $P$. These would be mathematically valid, but are excluded since that would make the exercise too easy.

Comment: what is $W$? Is it a subset of $P$ or subspace

Comment: You should take polynomials of degree at least 3 that satisfy that condition. If the degree is exactly equal to 3, the set is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the a polynomial of degree $3$ such that the condition holds is of the form
$$c(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$
with $c\not=0$ which is not a linear space because it does not contain the zero polynomial.

Indeed, as  $$ you can take the set of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ for which the condition holds, that is the one generated by the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$:
$$V=\{c(x-1)(x-2)(x-3): c\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
Evidently $V\subset A$, and $V\not=A$ because $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\in A\setminus V$.

On the other hand, as $W$ you can take the set of all polynomials of any degree such that $p(1)=0$. We have that $A\subset W$ and $W\not=A$ because $(x-1)\in W\setminus A$.